# Where to Find a word file in Wordpress theme

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove **grlryt2bdKIyfMSOhzd1eA.woff** from my wordpress theme for increase site speed. But unable to find it, where is it's location.
my site is [Design Spicy](http://designspicy.com). I am trying since 2 hour but unable to find it.

Comment: There are no files with that name being loaded on the home page.

Comment: but in the tools pingdom i found this file 81kb...

Comment: If you inspect the page, while it's loading, and observe all loaded assets, the one you listed isn't one of them. In fact, only two `woff` files are loaded...and neither are that size.

Comment: Yes but if I remove them I save 81kb of my loading time , I am using jetpack plugin so I guess the file is from jetpack ?

Comment: try mozilla you can find the woff

Answer (score 0):

That file is part of the custom font Roboto you are using and is not a file on your server, but loaded from 'fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/'.